# Regex: Endless loop

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex in order to check for a valid URL. But it keeps falling in an endless loop and I don't know why. Keeping away the ?true=bla solves the problem.

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

with the url
    http://google.com?true=bla

What is the problem in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by an endless loop?  What language are you talking about?

Comment: Regex can have infinite loops and crash your software, this is what I'm talking about. I'm doing java, sorry to forget mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
(https?:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*?)\.([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]*?)\/(.*)
```

This will match http or https URL's with or without subdomains and/or query strings

Comment: `(https?:\/\/)([\w-]*)\.([\w.-]*)\/(.*)` is much shorter.